# css: is there any difference between hexadecimal color value and hexadecimal color value in shorthand?

Tags: css

css:

```
h1 {color:#000;}
```

html:

```
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
```

Question:

Is there any difference between `color:#000;`(hexadecimal color value in shorthand) and `color:#000000`(hexadecimal color value)?

Comment: No, except that one is shorter. :-)

Comment: Define "difference" - there's a difference that it's 3 less characters to type, but that's not what you mean... define what you mean by difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference at all. As per [the CSS Color Module spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color):

> The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example, #fb0 expands to #ffbb00. This ensures that white (#ffffff) can be specified with the short notation (#fff)...

Answer (score 1):

No there is no difference. They describe exactly the same. Only shorter and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

No difference.

Any color like #XXYYZZ can be written as #XYZ

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in both color but `color: #000000;` is more preferable to use for eg you can change with more colors that is `#010101;` but you can't do this in `#000;`

With first #000 it can select 8-bit color but with second #000000 it can select 16-bit color